# google sheets copy formatting from active sheet to every other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I really need your help. After 2 days, I'm still on "ZERO".

I need a script that copies all the formats from an active sheet to every other sheet.
It would be nice to have the conditional formatting, alternating colors and data validation too.
I think it's not so hard, but I'm really new in script writing.

This is the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mOkm_r4rngPXTkIerSQJKxRih31sM7XoZCZVnoHUc5M/edit?usp=sharing

The code so far:

```
enter function copyFormatting(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var copyTo = ss.getSheetByName('agent2');
var range = copyTo.getRange(1, 1, copyTo.getMaxColumns(), copyTo.getMaxRows());
sheet.getBandings()[0].copyTo(copyTo.getRange(1,1)),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
}

function allcopyFormatting() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
  if(sheet.getSheetName() !== "detroit"){ // if you dont want to use the formatting on this sheet
sheet.activate();
copyFormatting(); // the function what yo like to run
  }
})
}
```

I was able to figure out and write some functions: clear formatting on all sheets, format row headers on all sheets, show a list of sheets, but this one is too hard for me.
Even if I try to model it first with the macro recorder.

I would be very grateful, if you could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out:

```
function allcopyFormatting() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
var sampleSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();  // from the spreadsheet select the active sheet
var maxRow =sampleSheet.getMaxRows();
var maxCol =sampleSheet.getMaxColumns();
var sampleRange = sampleSheet.getRange(1,1,maxRow,maxCol);
allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
  if(sheet.getSheetName() !== "detroit"){ // if you dont want to use the formatting on this sheet
sheet.activate();
var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();  // from the spreadsheet select the active sheet
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1,1);
sampleRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true})  // it copies the formatting
  }
})
}
```

#### Reference

- [Copy To](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Answer (score 0):

Try [insertSheet(options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(Object))  and if that doesn't  work the try [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))