# Copy formatting automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Good Morning!
I have a sheet with a master and several individual sheets, and occasionally I'll have to add a column. This works fine on the master sheet, cell formats just shift over, data validation follows suit. On the individual sheets though I have to go and copy/paste "format only" to make everything right again.

Is there a way on google sheets to automatically copy the format of one sheet, to the rest of the sheets? Or perhaps a way to make a sheet's formatting just follow whatever another sheet has?

Answer (score 0):

It's not automatic, but you should be able to copy the cells where the formatting is correct, then highlight cells in the other sheet, go to the 'Edit' menu, select 'Paste special' then 'Paste format only'.

Make sure you select an equivalent range between 'Copy' and 'Paste special'. You should be able to select entire columns.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can refer to an answer from a quite similar post about [google sheets copy formatting from active sheet to every other sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760236/15384825), where an Apps Script was suggested to automate the copying of a sheet format to all other sheets.